# Как изменить форму pagination в swiper?

Tags: jquery, css, html5

Добрый день! Есть установленный swiper slider, необходимо изменить стандартный swiper-pagination с кружков на квадраты и еще изменить цвет активного с синего на красный? Гугл к сожалению мне не помог в поиске ответа, буду признателен за любую информацию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  border-radius:0; // либо вообще удалить эту строчку из CSS
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  background: #f00; // красный цвет для активного квадрата
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но border-radius:none не сработал. Помогло поставить border-radius: 0;

Comment: @ВячеславГурьянов, да, прошу прощения. Совсем забыл, что для "обнуления" свойста нужно ставить 0. Исправил ответ

Answer (score 0):

http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#pagination
This parameter allows totally customize pagination bullets, you need to pass here a function that accepts index number of pagination bullet and required element class name (className). Only for bullets pagination type
For example, with this code, we can add slide number into pagination bullet:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  //...
  renderBullet: function (index, className) {
    return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + '</span>';
  }
});
```